# Changing Mailto recipient through Javascript based on Selection Form

Tags: javascript, forms, email, if-statement, mailto

I'm trying to set up a HTML Form that will allow users to email comments or questions to different departments of our company. I do not have back-end access to the website...it's a corporate template we cannot adjust. So, I can't us PHP or other preferred ways to get this done.

I have pretty good understanding of HTML & CSS...but never dealt with javascript.

I have the form built with a select menu for 4 different departments. then inputs for name, email, and then textarea for their comment.

I set it all up and the form worked when I sent it to my single email address. However, I'd like the mailto: address to change based on what option is selected.

I've read a lot into it...and it looks like it needs to be a combination of "onchange" event...a variable to represent the email...and the "if else if, else if" condition.

I just have no idea how to put it together in javascipt...What i've tried doesn't work, and I'm really just not familiar enough with java to make it work.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated

Thanks,
Folfer

---Update---
Here's what I have for the basic HTML Form

```
<form action="MAILTO:XXXXX@XXXX.com" enctype="text/plain" method="post">
<div><label for="Department">Department:</label>
<select>
<option value="News">News</option>
<option value="Prog">Programming</option>
<option value="Prom">Promotions</option>
<option value="Eng">Engineering</option>
</select></div>
<div><label for="name">Your Name:</label> <input name="name" type="text" /></div>
<div><label for="mail">Your E-mail:</label> <input name="email" type="email" /></div>
<div><label for="msg">Message:</label><textarea name="message" style="margin-top: -20px; margin-bottom: 0px; height: 60px;"></textarea></div>
<div><button type="submit">Send your message</button><button type="reset">Clear</button></div>
</form>
```

I had some CSS to spruce it up, but this is the basic HTML.

Comment: Please include the HTML markup for the form.

Comment: The mailto address? Are you trying to `action="mailto:`? Stop. [It doesn't work](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html). You **need** server side support for this.

Comment: @Quentin nice, but don't you think the article you referred is a little outdated?

Comment: @VahidND — No. It still holds true.